# How to desable "Explore this data" from the Power Bi Service Application shared to endUsers

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I don't want that the endUser have access to "Explore this data" from power BI Application.

Can you help me to find a solution to not allow enduser to explore data .

I couldn't find it either in the admin portal or in the power bi desktop settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the dataset, go to `Manage permissions` in PBI Service. In there remove the `Allow recipients to build content with the data associated with this semantic model` option.

See: [Share access to a semantic model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-datasets-share)

Comment: Thanks it works but I didn't understand the difference between the same access that we can enable it and desable it in Audience's manage access.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-create-distribute-apps